# How to change HTML text into Simple String in android

Tags: android, html

I want to receive a HTML text but i can't decode it can anyone help me how can i decode this HTML text and how to show same as show as web.

My Array:

```
["<h2>Terms &amp; Conditions<\/h2>\r\n\r\n<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus<\/p>\r\n\r\n<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus<\/p>\r\n\r\n<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus<\/p>\r\n"]
```

My Code:-

```
     public class InformationInnerShow extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
        Boolean result = true;
        String des;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);

                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                  //  Log.d("",jsonArray.getString(0)+"");
                    Log.d("result",jsonArray+"");
                    des = jsonArray.toString();
                    Log.d("dps",des+"");
                }
            }catch (IOException |JSONException e){
                result = false;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            //super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if(result){
                des = Html.fromHtml(des).toString();
                Log.d("des",des+"");
                    textView.setText(des);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(InnnerInformation.this, "Somthing Bad Happened try againg later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

My Page look like that :-

[image]

I am new android developing please help me Thanks in Advance!

Comment: HttpClient and NameValue pair is deprecated one. please use jsonobject and UrlConnection manager

Comment: Thanks @Madhu but this is my question.

Comment: did you try to use Html.fromHtml().toString();. I think this will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
des = jsonArray.toString();
```

with

```
des = jsonArray.getString(0).toString();
```

Because your response is an array,if you call `toString()` on it,it will return a string like **["xxx"]**,so you should get string at nth and call `toString()`on it,then use `Html.fromHtml()` to display it as html text.

Answer (score 1):

Use Html.fromHtml(String) method to convert your html in spnned.
Html class of android does not suuprt all tags of html

for detail please go to this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html